# How to perform the following query with Elasticsearch Java API?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using spring data elasticsearch, I want to be able to perform the following search query on my index "fruits" of type "fruit":

```
{
   'sort': {'fruitid': 'desc'}, 
   'query': {
      'query_string': {
         'query': u'Banana AND (start:>=1492274000000) AND (end:<=1386842400000)'
      }
   }, 
   'facets': {
      'fruit_color': {
          'terms': {'field': 'fruit_color', 'size': 5}
      }, 
      'fruit_weight': {
          'terms': {'field': 'fruit_weight', 'size': 5}
      }
}
```

How do I do this with the Java API? Note I do not want to use any model class.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/search-facets.html


I guess facet replaced by aggregations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java code below shows you how to create two `TermFacetRequest` for the fruit color and weight and how to add them to your query by calling `withFacet()`. It also shows you how to add the `query_string` query using the `QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery()` method call.

```
// create the fruit color facet
TermFacetRequest fruitColor = new TermFacetRequest("fruit_color");
fruitColor.setFields("fruit_color");
fruitColor.setSize(5);

// create the fruit weight facet
TermFacetRequest fruitWeight = new TermFacetRequest("fruit_weight");
fruitWeight.setFields("fruit_weight");
fruitWeight.setSize(5);

SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withPageable(new PageRequest(0, 10))
    .withQuery(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("Banana AND (start:>=1492274000000) AND (end:<=1386842400000)"))                
    .withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("fruitId").order(SortOrder.DESC))                
    .withIndices("fruit").withTypes("fruit")
    .withFacet(fruitColor)            <--- add the fruit color facet
    .withFacet(fruitWeight);          <--- add the fruit weight facet
```